# Make sure a function ends before the app close - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, cycle

I'm making an app using flutter, that has a cache Database. The update process Truncates the tables before inserting new data from the server.

Currently, If I close the app while the update function is running, The update is interrupted in middle and the data is not completely updated.

How Can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use an `application_state` flag

You can create a table that doesn't get truncated with the update a call it `migrations` or `updates` .
Before you start an update insert a record in that table with a flag called `application_state` with value `updating`.
When your update is completed change it's value to `updated`.
Whenever you open your app , see if `application_state` is `updating` , to rerun your update again because it failled .
Note that you can use this table to track user updating too, using `timesteps` or some other logic ...

Comment: Very interesting answer. I thought of somewhat the same thing. Like duplicate the database and save a value to shared preference while updating. When app opens. It will use the duplicated database if app was closed while updating. So offline functionality will be working too.